# Informix retain update lock option through Spring

Tags: java, database, spring, informix

In Informix, there are isolation levels similar to all other databases. But to use pessimistic locking, or select for update option, we have to add an extra option *RETAIN UPDATE LOCKS* while setting isolation level. Find documentation [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1169.htm)

```
SET ISOLATION TO COMMITTED READ RETAIN UPDATE LOCKS
```

This feature is kind of unique to Informix. In our application, default isolation is *DIRTY READ*. But we want some of the calls to be in *COMMITTED READ* isolation. For that we use [@Transactional](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) of Spring.

But unfortunately, through Spring we could not find a way to set above option *RETAIN UPDATE LOCK*. How we can achieve this using Spring or do we have any work around?

Comment: do you have informix dialect configured?

Comment: @BorysZibrov: we are not using hibernate. we use basic jdbctemplate of spring.

Comment: yeah, what I was trying to get at is that seems like this should be handled by some component aware part of your system

Comment: have you seen that article https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-isolation/ here IBM describes how they did similar stuff for WebSphere. So you probably want some kind of InformixDataSourceAdapter or something

Comment: Are you sure you want the RETAIN UPDATE LOCKS option?  If you update a row, the update lock is converted to an x-lock until commit regardless.  What this option affects is what happens if you have a cursor on `SELECT * FROM SomeTable FOR UPDATE` and you _don't_ update the row.  As the row is fetched, an update lock is applied; if you don't change the row, the update lock is released by default (but if you change the row, the update lock becomes an x-lock).  With RETAIN UPDATE LOCKS, your transaction can reselect the data for rows it did not update in the first pass confident that it is locked.